# MongoDb - Duplicate index fields for sharding purposes?

Tags: database, mongodb, performance, indexing, sharding

I want to build a cluster to store logging data. Each document has several fields but these are the key ones:

- user_id (medium cardinality)
- identifier (this has an extremely high cardinality but is not guaranteed to be unique across users, it can be a UPC for example)
- channel (low cardinality)
- timestamp

The collection is expected to have over 1 billion documents so sharding and performance are important here.

Now nearly **all** high-frequency queries to the collection will have `user_id` in them because the logs are displayed in the UI to each user uniquely. Most queries will be on `user_id` + `identifier`. Some queries will be time bound. Some queries also use `channel` but not all. `user_id` is a monotonically increasing field.

I want to shard on `hashed(user_id)`. One ideal index is `{"user_id": 1, "identifier": 1, "timestamp": 1}` so I made that. I tried sharding on `hashed(user_id)` but it did not work in this case and I realized `user_id` must be of the same type. However, making an index of `{"user_id": "hashed", "identifier": 1, "timestamp": 1}` is also impossible since compound keys with a hash are disallowed.

What is my best option here?

- create one index with just `hashed(user_id)` so I can shard on it and then another index with `{"user_id": 1, "identifier": 1, "timestamp": 1}`? I would incur a storage penalty here.
- don't hash the `user_id` even if it's monotonically increasing and instead shard on `{"user_id": 1, "identifier": 1}`? I'm not sure if there are disadvantages here compared to simply sharding on `hashed(user_id)`
- some other option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that MongoDB 4.4 allows for compound indexes with a single hashed field: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/hashed-sharding/

If you can't easily upgrade to 4.4, given that storage pressure is high here with the large number of documents and that most queries will contain both `user_id` and `identifier`, sharding on `{"user_id": 1, "identifier": 1}` sounds like the best option you have here. It will allow these queries to be fast at the expense of your other queries that need to search across all identifiers per user or time-based queries.

I'm not sure of a better solution on a version less than MongoDB 4.4.

Comment: This is great timing, it seems like version 4.4 solves the issue with my use case perfectly -- thanks!

Answer (score 1):

> create one index with just hashed(user_id) so I can shard on it and
> then another index with { "user_id": 1, "identifier": 1, "timestamp":
> 1 }? I would incur a storage penalty here.

You can only have one shard key (and this needs to be an indexed, single or a compound fields). In case of a hashed index field for the shard key, as of MongoDB v4.2, it can be only a single field index.

Querying a sharded collection with criteria using a shard key (or prefix of a compound shard key), will be a targeted query. The `mongos` will access the required shard(s), only. Hence, it will be an efficient query.

Querying without a shard key as part of the query criteria will only result in a scatter-gather operation - all the shards in the cluster will be accessed. Even, if there is an index on the queried field(s), it will still be scattered operation.

So, choosing a shard key plays, perhaps the most important part, of sharding cluster setup.

See [Targeted Operations vs. Broadcast Operations](https://docs.mongodb.com/v4.2/core/sharded-cluster-query-router/#targeted-operations-vs-broadcast-operations).

> don't hash the user_id even if it's monotonically increasing and
> instead shard on {"user_id": 1, "identifier": 1}? I'm not sure if
> there are disadvantages here compared to simply sharding on
> hashed(user_id)

Your querying needs should drive your shard key selection (and I have already noted above about shard keys).

MongoDB v4.4 (most recent) allows [Hashed Sharding on a Compound Hashed Index](https://docs.mongodb.com/master/core/hashed-sharding/).